# It works fine in Android Studio also in my Phone(SONY) but other phone it says stopped working

Tags: javascript, java, android

[image]

In my Sony Xperia phone it works fine no errors

my Logcat:

```
04-13 17:53:18.388 2500-2500/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-13 17:53:18.622 2500-2500/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10-1/lib/x86
04-14 01:53:29.489 2500-2500/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10-1/lib/x86
04-14 01:53:29.647 2500-2500/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-14 01:53:29.683 2500-2819/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

[ 04-14 01:53:29.698  2500: 2500 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaacc950, tid 2500


[ 04-14 01:53:29.755  2500: 2819 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae4526f0, tid 2819
04-14 01:53:29.770 2500-2819/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-14 01:53:29.890 2500-2819/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-14 01:53:29.890 2500-2819/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa422c20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-14 01:53:37.666 2500-2820/com.example.shyeilla.myfirstgamev10 I/System.out: 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks in advance who wants to help me

Comment: What do you mean with *in some other phone*?

Comment: when i try my apps to other phone it stopped working, see picture sir thanks a lot

Comment: that´s not the error stacktrace, there must be more with any exception warning....